# The caret disappears or won't show up in UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm having trouble with the caret of `UITextfield`s.

Whenever I tap on the textfield the caret doesn't show, but otherwise the textfield is working properly. The problem is similar to the problem described [here](http://www.spotlessicode.com/blog/posts/uitextfield-editing-text-and-cursor-disappear-solution) (already tried the solution written there as well).

I noticed that whenever I load a viewcontroller and tap on a textfield (or programatically make it the first responder) it *does* show a caret, but as soon as I tap another textfield or make a textfield resign its first responder status *no textfield will show its caret anymore* (unless I go back and reload the viewcontroller again).

Got no clue as of why this is happening. I *am* using a custom font throughout the app. But I'm not sure if that's what making the caret disappear, as I've used custom fonts before with no problem whatsoever.

**EDIT:**

I think I've at least found *why* the problem occurs. It is related to me overriding the `becomeFirstResponder` and `resignFirstResponder`.

My code looks like:

```
extension UITextField {
    open override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let willBecomeResponder = super.becomeFirstResponder()

        if willBecomeResponder {
            backgroundColor = .red
            layer.borderColor = .blue
        }

        return willBecomeResponder
    }

    open override func resignFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        let willResignResponder = super.resignFirstResponder()

        if willResignResponder {
            backgroundColor = .blue
            layer.borderColor = .red
        }
        return willResignResponder
    }
}
```

Overriding those methods in the extension makes the caret disappear.
I'm thinking this most likely happens because `UITextField` itself does some...'caret-management' in it's own implementation of those methods.
More so because even `return super.becomeFirstResponder()` and no custom code in the overridden method makes the caret disappear.

#### My question therefore is; how can one solve this problem without making a custom `UITextField` subclass?

Calling `super` obviously just calls the `UIResponder`'s implementation, but the docs specifically mention:

> **becomeFirstResponder()**
>   You can override this method in your custom responders to update your object's state or perform some action such as highlighting the selection. If you override this method, **you must call super at some point in your implementation**.

So I need to call super I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved my problem by overriding `isFirstResponder` and altering the textfield based on the `super.isFirstResponder` there.

Looks like:

```
open override var isFirstResponder: Bool {
    get {
        let responder = super.isFirstResponder

        backgroundColor = (responder) ? .red : .blue
        layer.borderColor = (responder) ? .blue : .red

        return responder
    }
}
```

I did noticed a *lot* of calls being sent to `isFirstResponder`, so maybe this isn't the most efficient way (if altering the textfield is a heavy op).